# Asymptotic expansion of a double integral with a Bessel function

Tags: integration, asymptotics, bessel-functions, surface-integrals, laplace-method

I am attempting to figure out the first term of the asymptotic expansion at $t \to \infty$ of the following double integral:
$$
     I(\tau) = \iint_{[\sqrt{\tau},\tau]^2}  \frac{e^{2(u+v)} I_1(2 (2\tau - u - v))}{(2\tau - u - v)\sqrt{uv}} d u d v
$$

My hypothesis is that: $I(t) \sim e^{4t} \sqrt \frac{\pi}{2t}$

I believe if I could make the **assumption 1** that the bessel function $I_1$ can be replaced by its asymptotic form $\frac{e^{z}}{\sqrt{2 \pi z}}$, then it seems quite doable. Indeed Mathematica seems to provide me with an answer for the input:

```
Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x y] (2 t - x - y)^(3/2)), {y, Sqrt[t], t}, {x, Sqrt[t], t}, Assumptions -> t > 1]
```

output: $$
\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t-\sqrt{t}}}{\sqrt[4]{t}}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\sqrt{t}-1}}\right)+\cot ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{t-\sqrt{t}}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{t}}
$$
Therefore, I can run "Series" on top of that and get it is equivalent to $\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi }{\sqrt{t}}$

Actually, it seems I could even make the **assumption 2** that it is also equivalent to taking the integration domain to $[0,\tau]^2$ for which I also get the same result with:

```
Integrate[1/(Sqrt[x y] (2 t - x - y)^(3/2)), {y, 0, t}, {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t > 1]
```

Would you know if there is any justification to make assumption 1 and potentially assumption 2 ? Or would you see another way to tackle such a problem ?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
A slight improvement to try to reduce the problem to a simple integral.
With change of variable $x = \tau - u$, $y = \tau - v$ we find:
\begin{equation}
e^{-4 \tau} I(\tau)
= 
\iint_{[0,\tau - \sqrt \tau]^2} e^{-2(x+y)} \frac{I_1(2(x+y))}{(x+y)\sqrt{(\tau - x)(\tau - y)}} d u d v 
\end{equation}
Further, with $s=x+y$ we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{-4 \tau} I(\tau) & = & 
\int_{0}^{\tau - \sqrt \tau} \int_{x}^{x+\tau-\sqrt \tau}
\frac{e^{-2s} I_1(2s)}{s \sqrt{(\tau -x )(\tau + x - s)}} d s d x\\
& = & \int_{0}^{\tau - \sqrt \tau} \int_0^{s} \frac{e^{-2s} I_1(2s)}{s \sqrt{(\tau -x )(\tau + x - s)}} d x d s \\
& + & \int_{\tau - \sqrt \tau}^{2(\tau - \sqrt \tau)} \int_{s-(\tau - \sqrt \tau)}^{\tau - \sqrt \tau} \frac{e^{-2s} I_1(2s)}{s \sqrt{(\tau -x )(\tau + x - s)}} d x d s \\
\end{eqnarray}
Now we can "easily" integrate the subintegrals, if I am not wrong we have:
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{(\tau -x )(\tau + x - s)}}
= 2 \sinh^{-1}\left(
    \sqrt \frac{\tau - x}{2\tau - s}
\right)
\end{equation}
But not sure how to deal with simple integrals with $I_1$ and $\sinh^{-1}$.

Comment: are u aware of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891384/asymptotic-expansion-of-multiple-integral-at-infty/3892765#3892765 ?

Comment: Hi @asgeige , yes I do and I am the same author. I remember you answered me on this topic: this is indeed based on the same line of research!